# How to Create a Fragments Application in Android?

Tags: java, android, fragment

i Want to create one Fragment Application.i used this Example [Example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/).But i Got many Errors.What are thr jar files to import Fragment Application?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to install the compatibility jar as outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).